# Converting String column to vector in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, vector, int

I want to convert a dataframe column to a vector because it has two category say girl, boy so i want to map girl as 1 and boy as 0 but i get the mapping in float. I  want it in integer.

My code

```
df=pd.read_csv('')
mapping={'girl':1,'boy':0}
df['gender'] = df['gender'].map(mapping)
```

Comment: Can you update your question with simplified of `df` variable?

Comment: Please also put on your result trace full